# How to filter countries with XSLT?

Tags: xslt

What I need is display in table all movies which origin from europe. For test I just want to filter just czech and france movies, but I allways get just czech movies. Heres is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet  [
<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
<!ENTITY copy   "&#169;">
<!ENTITY reg    "&#174;">
<!ENTITY trade  "&#8482;">
<!ENTITY mdash  "&#8212;">
<!ENTITY ldquo  "&#8220;">
<!ENTITY rdquo  "&#8221;"> 
<!ENTITY pound  "&#163;">
<!ENTITY yen    "&#165;">
<!ENTITY euro   "&#8364;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body xml:space="preserve">
<xsl:variable name="europe_countries">
  <xsl:choose>  
    <xsl:when test="'CZ'">CZ</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="'FR'">FR</xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Movies</th>
        <th>Countries of origin</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="movies/movie[substring(country_code,1) = $europe_countries]">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="movie_name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="country_code_full"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do you have any idea where is the problem? Hope someone could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: <xsl:variable name="europe_countries">
  <xsl:choose>  
    <xsl:when test="'CZ'">CZ</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="'FR'">FR</xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>..check this block

Comment: i know that there is the problem, but i don't know how can it be ok

Comment: How is this different from your previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796640/display-european-countries-with-xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concept to define a variable is wrong.
You can not state whether particular country code is "european" before you know this code (and now you don't).

Each test you wrote (e.g. `<xsl:when test="'CZ'">`) is fulfilled,
because you test here a non-empty string, which in boolean context gives *true*.

Now move on to how it should be done.

Start from definig a string variable, containing codes of European countries, separated with space.

```
<xsl:variable name="europe_countries" select="'CZ DE FR'"/>
```

Then you can write the following *for-each* loop:

```
<xsl:for-each select="movies/movie[contains($europe_countries, country_code)]">
```

I assume that source *movie* tag contains a child *country_code* tag (2 chars).
So the above *select* condition selects *movie* tags which meet the following predicate:

Does *europe_countiries* variable contain the text given in the child *country_code* tag of the *movie* in question.

Of course, in the target version you should add remaining European contry codes.